# How to copy item A to item B without loosing the ID of B?

Tags: sitecore-api

I want to make the item B (destination) identical to item A (source), without changing the ID of B.
I tried with the following:

```
var sourceXmlString = source.GetOuterXml(false);
var sourceXml = XElement.Parse(sourceXmlString);
sourceXml.SetAttributeValue(XName.Get("id"), destination.ID.ToString());
sourceXml.SetAttributeValue(XName.Get("parentid"), destination.Parent.ID.ToString());

// Paste the final xml to update the existing item
destination.Parent.Paste(sourceXmlString, false, PasteMode.Merge);
```

but this strategy does not seem to work for Checkbox fields: the source item has an unchecked checkbox field (the standard value of that checkbox filed is checked) but after running the code the destination item shows the checkbox checked.

Comment: Why not use powershell to copy the data from the fields of item A to item B?

Comment: If my understanding is correct for your requirement then I would suggest you to use Clone for this. Here is a post that might guide you in doing so. https://sitecorejunkie.com/2013/04/27/automagically-clone-new-child-items-to-cloned-parent-items-in-the-sitecore-cms/

Comment: I have N sites and I need a command that makes the destination site identical to the source site, doing also relink. My code is a customization of Sitecore.SmartCommands - it is executed from a content editor right click menù item (it is in a pipeline). I can't use clones, there will be two independent item instances.

Comment: @Amitabh is correct. For your purposes, cloning seems best fit

Comment: These sites will be managed by different editors, so they must be independent; if the editor of site A updates an item of site A, the same item in the site B should not be modified. Now we are developing these sites so we are working on a command to copy a site A to a site B without changing item IDs (items are serialized with Unicorn...)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Sitecore.Data.Managers.ItemManager.CreateItem` method. There is overloaded version that takes item id:

```
public static Item CreateItem(string itemName, Item destination, ID templateId, ID newId)
```

then you can copy each field values.